# Can my brother fix his credit?

Tags: credit-score, credit, home-loan, co-sign

My brother co-signed with my mother on a house payment. My mother didn't make the payments, but my brother pulled his fair weight. Now the house is getting foreclosed, and my brother's credit is shot. My brother's always been perfect with his own loan payments, credit card payments, etc. but this house payment has completely destroyed his credit. Is there anything short of taking years to meticulously build his credit back up that he can do?

Answer (score 12):

Well, he *could* negotiate with the bank to pay off the loan before the foreclosure takes effect. That would obviously cost him a large pile of cash but might remove the foreclosure, and possibly the late payments, from his record.

But the real answer is that, having signed the note, he should have been making sure payments occurred so it never got *close* to foreclosure. That's what he promised the bank he would do. Having failed to do so, he really isn't in a position to complain when they tell other businesses that he didn't meet that promise.

Comment: I would go a step further, for posterity, and say that the real answer is to not co-sign a loan which you are unable to fully bear on your own. Mixing family/friends and money is a recipe for trouble, as shown here.

Answer (score 10):

In a nutshell, not really.  That's the risk you take when you co-sign for someone.  The lender only made the loan because of the strength of your brother's credit, not your mother's, so his reputation (in the form of his credit rating) is going to take the hit because of his mother's behaviors.

***The one thing he can do*** is this:  The credit bureaus allow you to add a comment or explanation to your credit file which may be helpful, provided potential creditors read it, which is never a guarantee.  It's worth trying though, so suggest to him to look into it.

Here's a link for him/you/anyone to look at that can help explain how this works and what effects it can have:

[Adding a comment to your credit file for negative items](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/help/add-written-statement-to-credit-report-6000.php)

I hope this helps.

Good luck!